# Javascript dropdown validation and alert

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have tried to get it to work but I simply can't find the mistake. Also I have no idea how to make the selection which you have not selected to turn red or some color to alert you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <select id='Selection' name='Selection'>
            <option value=''>Select</option>
            <option value='1'>user1</option>
            <option value='2'>user2</option>
            <option value='3'>user3</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <select id='Candidate' name='Candidate'>
            <option value=''>Select</option>
            <option value='1'>candidate1</option>
            <option value='2'>candidate2</option>
            <option value='3'>candidate3</option>
        </select>  
        <br>  
        <input type='button' onclick='Validate()' value='select' />
        <script>
            function Validate()
            {
              if(document.getElementById('Selection').value == '' ||
                 document.getElementById('Candidate').value == '' ||)                
              {
                alert('Please complete all selections');
                return false;
              }
              return true;
            }       
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: fyi, you removed both `||` operators in your edit, you still need the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra `||` in you if condition, this will cause a syntax error, remove it (**the last one not both**). To change the element that has an invalid value you can just use css but you'll have to check them individually.

Comment: But how to turn the unselected selection red or sth?

Comment: @user1794625 you can set its style e.g. `document.getElementById('Candidate').style.border = 'red';` or what ever style want to set.